# PLSQL BLOCK keeps executing

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
    attrbVal VARCHAR2(5);
    updateAttrbVal varchar2(1);
BEGIN
    Select Attrb_val into attrbVal from system_feature_config where feature_attrb = 'Distributor Group';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(attrbVal);
    IF (attrbVal = 'ON') then
        updateAttrbVal := '1';
    ELSE
        updateAttrbVal := '0';
    END IF;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Update system_feature_config SET Attrb_val= '''||updateAttrbVal||''' WHERE feature_attrb=''VA_STATE_TAX_TYPE''';
    COMMIT;
END;
```

plsql block keeps executing and have to stop execution manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "keeps executing" means that it never finishes, I presume that it is because table to be updated (`system_feature_config`) has been modified in another session which wasn't committed (or rolled back) yet, so your code has to wait until it is released.

What to do? Commit, or roll back.

Comment: thanks @Littlefoot it is working now, there was some uncommitted session.